# Attempting to rename Service Config file throws exception in Azure Tools

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, azure

I work on an Azure-hosted ASPNET website project that was first developed years ago. Right now the project is in VS2010.

Ran into an exception in the tools while trying to update the project to use latest SDK & host operating system.  Trying to rename a ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file causes Visual Studio to report this:

Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.

I actually have two branches of this project.  One branch was not a big problem to update.  But before I tried to update the other branch I installed the latest Azure SDK for VS2012 (I'm planning to mirgrate).  So I thought that might be the reason this started happening.

I tried reinstalling "Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - v2.1" but that had no effect.

Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 0):

i've just met the same issue. Here is how i corrected it.

Open the folder of your ccproj file. Open ccproj.user file with a Notepad and check what is the default configuration defined in the file.
Open the configuration and delete RemoteDebuggerConnectorCertificateThumbprint entry in the xml file.
Restart VS and that's done.

Hope it helps